# watching videolectures.net on mac

Tags: macos, adobe, wmv

How can I watch a [lecture](http://videolectures.net/mlss06tw_roweis_mlpgm/#) from videolectures.net on a Mac? I have OSX 10.12.6 and the Flip4Mac is not working/outdated (in particular, this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/player/wmcomponents.mspx) on the help [page](http://videolectures.net/site/help/) has expired. I just downloaded Chrome, so I'm not sure what's going on when I receive the following error message:

`Your browser does not support playback of available video formats. Please install Adobe Flash player or upgrade to a more modern browser.`

I also tried on Safari and Chromium after downloading Adobe Flash...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That wasn't my intention. I thought it might be relevant to the community as many people here probably have macs and want to learn cs through videolectures.net

Comment: If there's a better place to post, please let me know!

Comment: But watching online videos isn't specific or unique to programming. There are actually other videos of other things, like cats, on the internet!

Comment: True, but to my knowledge, videolectures is supposed to be a useful resource for programming. I have no issues watching videos of cats on the internet! Somehow, I think the site is outdated for mac users, and I was wondering if people in this community had navigated the same issue. Do you have a suggestion for where I might migrate this question?

Comment: Have you tried installing Adobe Flashplayer as suggested?

Comment: @jmh: Yeah, I downloaded Flash and tried versions on both Safari and Chromium but no luck

Comment: I just read that the clips were only playable by PCs using Media Player.  Maybe thats dated.  It was a link on the lectures page.

Answer (score 1):

Flip4Mac is still maintained but does not work with Sierra or high sierra. Latest version works for Mac system 10.6.8 thru 10.11.6. If you system is included in this range, you can purchase Flip4Mac from [here.](https://www.telestream.net/flip4mac/overview.htm)  If you are running a newer system than 10.11.6 you can purchase an app called [Switch Player.](https://www.telestream.net/switch/overview.htm) Switch Player converts wmv files into a format compatible with Quicktime.

Answer (score 0):

Tried Firefox just now (v60.0.1), and it worked with Flash